# Basic example of a scriptable plugin for Firefox in C++ with VS2005/8

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scripting, npapi

My experience to write a plugin for Firefox is below zero. Is someone out there who could point me to sample code on how to get this accomplished in C++ with VS2005/8?

What I need to do with JavaScript in the hosting html page is something like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("MyFFPlugin");

var value = obj.CalculateValue;

// Work with calculated value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDK has basic samples on how to write mozzila plugins which can be downloaded here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/tools/sdk/

Here is the official mozilla plugin site http://www.mozilla.org/projects/plugins/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Nixysa http://code.google.com/p/nixysa/, which wraps NPAPI. From the site:

> Nixysa is a framework written in
>   Python to automatically generate glue
>   code for NPAPI plugins (plugins for
>   browsers such as Google Chrome or
>   Firefox), letting you easily expose
>   C++ classes to Javascript from a
>   simple IDL representation.  Nixysa was
>   originally conceived for the needs of
>   O3D, but is flexible enough to support
>   a wide range of use cases.
>
> Try it
>
> Check out the code following the
>   instructions here and try the sample
>   in examples/complex.

The sample includes a Visual Studio 2005 project.